# MethodNotAllowedHttpException while submitting form in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need update some record and this is form action in my blade

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/collaborators/{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id }}">
```

controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $projectId, $collaboratorId)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
            'status'  => 'required',
        ]);

        DB::table('permissions')
            ->where('project_id', $projectId)
            ->where('collaborator_id', $collaboratorId)
            ->update(['status' => $request->input('status')]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('info','Your Permission has been updated successfully');



 }
```

routes

```
Route::put('projects/{projects}/collaborators/{id}',['uses'=>'ProjectCollaboratorsController@update',]);
```

when click update button generate following error

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

how can solve this

Comment: In your route you have defined `put`  method and your form is using `post` method you should have to add hidden input in your form.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tiger mentioned in comment,

> In your route you have defined put method and your form is using post
>   method you should have to add hidden input in your form.

Add `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` after your opening `form` tag. Like below:

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/collaborators/{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id }}"

<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```